# Why does ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE does not work in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm creating table in snowflake using copy into clause, the values are coming from another table.
now I want to raise an error if in the table I have more columns than the new one.
for example I have in the new table 13 columns, and want to raise exception if the current record I'm trying to insert has 14 columns.
for that I used the parameter ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH and set this to TRUEv within the file_format = () clause.
the data I want to insert is file, pipe delimited, which sometimes when parsing it we get more columns than we except (14 instead of 13 ex.).

```
file_format = (format_name =  MY_FORMAT, ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = 
TRUE)
```

suppose to work... but not working.

anybody saw thing like this before?

Comment: Please add more details so we can reproduce the error. Any sample data?

Comment: How do you know the parameter is not working? Can you provide a sample of source/target table and copy into command?

Comment: I loaded the table again and the records with 14 columns inserted

Comment: Question: is the ON_ERROR option of your COPY command set to ABORT_STATEMENT? It might be worth sharing the whole COPY INTO statement. Also take a look at: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HowTo-Load-non-deterministic-number-of-columns-from-source-data-set-into-target-table

Comment: well, my ON_ERROR is set to throw away rows with error and keep loading. it does work with verifications error

Comment: As a note, ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH is defaulted to TRUE, so no need to add it to your file_format definition, but if you do, I believe the comma is unnecessary.  If your ON_ERROR is set to continue, then it won't throw an error.  You'll just get a status that the file was partially loaded.

Comment: @MikeWalton does it mean that a row with more than 13 columns will not be inserted into the table? cause thats what I'm trying to get, and this is not working for me.

Comment: Can you share the definition of your file format?

Comment: @MikeWalton my file format is:
    type = CSV
    field_delimiter='|'
    escape_unenclosed_field=none
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE
    encoding = 'windows-1255'

do you have any idea how to change escape_unenclosed_field value to any letter from a to z?